# In R shiny how to move table and related inputs, generated using rhandsontable, into a modal dialogue box?

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, rhandsontable

I am very new to the rhandsontable package and the use of modal dialogues in R shiny, but rendering reactive tables in modal dialogue boxes will be very important for the types of models I run. I need to learn how to do this well!

The below MWE generates a simple reactive table that works like the type of table I often use, for the sake of example. How would I move all of the items that currently appear below the "Show" action button, when running, into a modal dialogue box?

Also the images below show what I'm trying to do.

MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h4("Click ´Show´ button below to trigger modal dialogue:"),
  
  actionButton("show","Show"),
  br(),br(),
  
  actionButton(inputId = "reset_input", label = "Reset"),
  br(),br(),
  
  rHandsontableOutput("two_by_two"),
  br(),
  
  tableOutput(outputId = "chg_data")
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(3, 4), row.names = c("C", "D"))
  
  output$two_by_two <- renderRHandsontable({
    input$reset_input # trigger rendering on reset
    rhandsontable(DF)
  })
  
  output$chg_data = renderTable({
    hot_to_r(req({input$two_by_two}))*2}, rownames = TRUE)
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What appears when running this MWE code:

[image]

What I would like to do:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  h4("Click ´Show´ button below to trigger modal dialogue:"),
  #tags$head(tags$style(" .modal-dialog{ width:800px}")),
  tags$head(tags$style(" .modal-body{ min-height:500px}")),
  actionButton("show","Show"),
  br(),br()
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  DF <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2), B = c(3, 4), row.names = c("C", "D"))
  
  output$two_by_two <- renderRHandsontable({
    input$reset_input # trigger rendering on reset
    rhandsontable(DF)
  })
  
  output$chg_data = renderTable({
    hot_to_r(req({input$two_by_two}))*2}, rownames = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    showModal(modalDialog(title = "my display",
                          
                            actionButton(inputId = "reset_input", label = "Reset"),
                            br(),br(),
                            rHandsontableOutput("two_by_two"),
                            br(),
                            tableOutput(outputId = "chg_data"),
                          
                          easyClose = TRUE, footer = NULL, class = 'success'
    ))
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]